# Is there a function to call for exporting graph to xml

Tags: mxgraph, jgraph, draw.io

I want to add a button to export the current diagram to an xml var.

I know that there's a button to export but i didn't understand the code that it use to export.

I am a newbie in coding so please help.

Comment: So you would like to save the current state of your graph object in xml format into a variable?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i want to do . Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current state of your `graph` object into `xml format` using the code below:

```
   var xml = "";

   let saveBtn = document.createElement('button');
   saveBtn.value = ' Save XML ' ;
   saveBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
       exportXML(); //on click trigger the exportXML() function;
   });

   function exportXML() {
    let encoder = new mxCodec();
    let result = encoder.encode(graph.getModel()); //where graph is the object you are using
    xml = mxUtils.getXml(result); //now the global variable 'xml' is assigned with the xml value of the graph
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, but is there a way to get the current graph into an xml variable;

i want to add a button in index.html, when you click on it it save the current graph into a variable .

Comment: @NickAth, When I use the above code I am not getting whole graph instead of <mxGraphModel><root><mxCell id="0"/><mxCell id="1" parent="0"/></root></mxGraphModel>   but actual xml is  having more detail.

Comment: Could you debug on the `graph` object? Try to console.log() the `graph.getChildCells();`, what does it return?